# Load modal after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Relevant page here:
http://marcmurray.net/test_sites/cans/news.php

I've been trying to load a message confirmation modal for a while after the user submits an email, but can't get it to work at all.

So far I've tried echoing the whole script out, triggering the script, and changing the hash in the URL and checking for that, which has worked in other areas of the site.

Adding functions like alerts and echoing text onto the page is working fine, but when I use the show method it doesn't work. That leads me to believe I am either escaping characters wrong, or misunderstand how modals work a little.
Can anyone see where I'm messing up?

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        // Checking For Blank Fields..
    if($_POST["vname"]==""||$_POST["vemail"]==""||$_POST["sub"]==""||$_POST["msg"]==""){
       echo "Please fill out everything! We need to know who you are, and why you want to get in touch with us!";}
    else
        {
        // Check if the "Sender's Email" input field is filled out
        $email=$_POST['vemail'];
                // Sanitize E-mail Address
        $email =filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
                // Validate E-mail Address
        $email= filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        $emailConfirmed=$_POST['vemail'];
        if (!$email){
          echo "Don't forget to include your email adress! Otherwise we can't get back to you.";
                }
                else
                {
                    $subject = $_POST['sub'];
                    $message = $_POST['msg'];
                    $headers =  'From:' . $emailConfirmed . "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
                    $headers .= 'Cc:' . $emailConfirmed . "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
                    // Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
                    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
                    // Send Mail By PHP Mail Function
                    mail("marc.murray.92@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
                    echo "<script>$('#thankyouModal').modal('show')</script>";
                };
    }
 }
?>
```

**HTML for the modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="thankyouModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Thank you for pre-registering!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Thanks for getting in touch!</p>                     
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Updated code to be simpler than initial question.

Comment: is it even sending the email? I think it is not...

Comment: Email sends, tested that in multplie browsers etc it works fine.

Comment: @MarcMurray What's not working? When I go to the site you mention and submit something in the "Get in Touch" section, I do get a modal.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of calling `modal show` method upfront let all the assets load first then call the `modal show` method.

```
echo "<script>
         $(window).load(function(){
             $('#thankyouModal').modal('show');
         });
    </script>";
```

Comment: Does this work? Because it doesn't for me

Answer (score 7):

Instead of echoing the script why not just detect your form submit with javascript and then display the modal?

Something like

```
$("form").on('submit', function(){
   $('.modal').show();
})
```

(If you're using JQuery)

Comment: I tried that at an earlier stage and it wasn't working, I feel like it has something to do with the page refreshing after the form is submitted but anything else I try (echoing out simpler divs, alerts, console logs) are all working.

Comment: Using ajax to submit the from and using the success and error callbacks to do what you want.

Comment: im facing similar issues but this does not work for me

Answer (score 2):

First problem i see in your example code is, unnecessary \ on following code.`echo "<script> \`. Remove it

Second: Are you including all required js and css files for boostrap modal? If you are not Please update the code with following lines of code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

At last there is no event triggered to open boostrap modal. Add following code to trigger the modal.

```
$(window).load(function(){
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Final code :

```
echo "<script>
            var newHTML = document.createElement ('div');
            newHTML.innerHTML =
            newHTML = document.createElement ('div');
            newHTML.innerHTML = ' <div id=\"myModal\" class=\"modal fade\" tabindex=\"-1\" role=\"dialog\"> <div class=\"modal-dialog\"><div class=\"modal-content\"><div class=\"modal-header\"></div>';
            document.body.appendChild (newHTML);
            $(window).load(function(){
                 $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
        </script>";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi there!
This code works insofar as it appends the modal HTML to the body, but again it doesn't show!
I've tried changing the hash around and checking for that to display it too, but the show method doesn't seem to be working in this instance at all.

Comment: Make sure that the required js&css libraries are loaded before your code is executed. and then you can improve your code as follows, `echo "<script>$(function() { $('#thankyouModal').modal('show'); });</script>";`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the problem..

```
 echo "<script>$('#thankyouModal').modal('show')</script>";
```

I would do this....

```
$var =   "<script>$(document).ready(function(){
             $('#thankyouModal').modal('show')
          });</script>";
```

And later print it on the right part inside your head at your html template.

Using your option and adding $(document).ready inside the script you are echoing dont think would work...the problem with the last option is that you will echo the script but jquery might not be yet fully loaded and it wont recognize it.

So, I suggest it to send it as a parameter and then print it.

If you are not using a framework and it is hard for you to pass a parameter, you can do it thought the URL and do something like my `project.com/result.php?submit=true`

and at your frontend you will read that variable

Like

```
if(isset($_GET["submit"]) && ($_GET["submit"]) ){
//echo your modal script 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that .in (sets opacity to 1) class which I believe should be set by Bootstrap does not show after submitting the form.

```
$('.modal').show().addClass('in');
```

Btw. you have an error in console

```
$(...).parsley(...).on is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#thankyouModal').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't submit multiple times
    this.submit(); // use the native submit method of the form element
     $('#thankyouModal').modal('show'); //Open the model
});
```

or *You can manually create a button after form submit and trigger click on that button to open the modal.*

```
$('#thankyouModal').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // don't submit multiple times
        $("form").submit(); // use the native submit method of the form element
 $('<button type="button" id="btnThankYou" class="hidden" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#thankyouModal">ThankYouButton</button>').appendTo('body');

//This will click the button and open the modal
    $("#btnThankYou" ).trigger("click");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As xkcd149 says, if you mean to load the modal in the same page without reloading, you should be using AJAX requests:

1. replace the onsubmit attribute of the form to a function that sends the request data

   ```
   window.onload = function() {
     var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
     for(var f in forms) {
       frm[f].onsubmit = xhr; // xhr is the function that sends the XHR
     }
   }
   ```
2. in the submit funcion used above, add success and error callbacks:

   ```
   function xhr(){
     var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
     ...
     client.onerror = xhrerr;
     client.onreadystatechange = handler;
     client.send(...);
     ...
   }
   ```
3. the success function should display the modal if the returned HTTP code is 200 (or whatever you want/need)

   ```
   function handler(){
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       var widget = document.getElementById("modal-body");
       // add content to the body of the modal
     } else {
     // manage error
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Place this links at your HEAD tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and then change this:

```
<script>$('#thankyouModal').modal('show')</script>
```

to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
<script>$('#thankyouModal').modal('show')</script>
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$modal =   "<script>$(document).ready(function(){
         $('#thankyouModal').modal('show')
      });</script>";


if(isset($_GET["submit"]) && ($_GET["submit"]) ){
 // after running other script
 echo $modal; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try as

```
$('#thankyouModal').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); // don't submit multiple times
this.submit(); // use the native submit method of the form element
 $('#thankyouModal').modal('show'); //Open the model
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should send form via ajax, so after submit event you don't have to refresh your page.

As long as you won't refresh your page, your modal will be load successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    // Checking For Blank Fields..
   $checkpost = false;
if($_POST["vname"]==""||$_POST["vemail"]==""||$_POST["sub"]==""||$_POST["msg"]==""){
   echo "Please fill out everything! We need to know who you are, and why you want to get in touch with us!";}
else
    {
    // Check if the "Sender's Email" input field is filled out
    $email=$_POST['vemail'];
            // Sanitize E-mail Address
    $email =filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            // Validate E-mail Address
    $email= filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $emailConfirmed=$_POST['vemail'];
    if (!$email){
      echo "Don't forget to include your email adress! Otherwise we can't get back to you.";
            }
            else
            {
 $checkpost = true;
                $subject = $_POST['sub'];
                $message = $_POST['msg'];
                $headers =  'From:' . $emailConfirmed . "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
                $headers .= 'Cc:' . $emailConfirmed . "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
                // Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
                $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
                // Send Mail By PHP Mail Function
                mail("marc.murray.92@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
                echo "<script>$('#thankyouModal').modal('show')</script>";
            };
}
```

}
?>

in html

```
<?php if($checkpost){ ?>
<script>
$('.modal').show();
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit too late to answer. But hopefully it might help others.

The below code worked for me where I am using a Post-Redirect-Get pattern.Open a modal after form submission.

```
window.onpageshow = function() {
    if (typeof window.performance != "undefined"
        && window.performance.navigation.type === 0) {
         $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Write down the following code.If you are using JQuery.

```
success: function(data)
    {
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
    }
```